# Using a print function to output to a new file

Tags: c++, ofstream

I have a program analyzing the number of distinct and total words in a text file and then writing it to a new output file. I've got the first part down, but I don't know how to get my print function to print onto the new text file. Printing the total words or distinct words onto the new file works but the Print2() function doesn't seem to work. Please take a look at the **//POINT OF INTEREST//** section, where i believe the problem stems.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
int distinctWord = 0;
using namespace std;

typedef int ItemType;

struct Node {
    string word;
    int count = 1;
    Node* left;
    Node* right;
};

class TreeType {
private:
    Node* root;
    void Insert(Node*& root, string word);
    void Destroy(Node*& root);
    void PrintTree(Node* root);
    void Print2File(Node* root, ofstream& fout);
public:
    TreeType() {root = nullptr;}
    ~TreeType();
    void PutItem(string word);
    void Print();
    void Print2(ofstream& fout);
};

void TreeType::Print() {
    PrintTree(root);
    cout << endl;
}

void TreeType::PrintTree(Node* root) {
    if (root == nullptr)
        return;
    PrintTree(root->left);
    cout << root->word << " " << root->count << endl;
    PrintTree(root->right);
}
///////////////POINT OF INTEREST///////////////////////////
///////////////POINT OF INTEREST///////////////////////////

void TreeType::Print2File(Node* root, ofstream& fout){
    if (root == nullptr)
        return;
    PrintTree(root->left);
    fout << root->word << " " << root->count << endl;
    PrintTree(root->right);
}

void TreeType::Print2(ofstream& fout) {
    Print2File(root, fout);
    cout << "Printed to another file" << endl;
}

///////////////POINT OF INTEREST///////////////////////////
///////////////POINT OF INTEREST///////////////////////////

void TreeType::PutItem(string word) {
    Insert(root, word);
}

void TreeType::Insert(Node*& root, string word) {
    if (root == nullptr) {
        root = new Node;
        distinctWord++;
        root->word = word;
        root->right = nullptr;
        root->left = nullptr;
        return;
    }
    if(root->word == word){
        root->count++;
        return;
    }else if (word < root->word)
        Insert(root->left, word);
    else
        Insert(root->right, word);
}

TreeType::~TreeType() {
    Destroy(root);
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    int totalwords = 0;
    ifstream file;
    string word;
    char c;
    ofstream fout;

    ifstream file;
    string filename;
    cout << "Enter name of file with text to analyze: ";
    cin >> filename;
    fin.open(filename.c_str());
    if (fin.fail()) {
        cout << "Error opening file.\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    cout << "\nAnalyzing " << filename << ".\n";

    TreeType t;

    while(!file.eof()){
        file.get(c);

        if(isalpha(c) || c == '\''){
            word += c;
            c = '\0';
        }else if(c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '-' || c == '.'){
            if(isalpha(word[0])){
                transform(word.begin(), word.end(), word.begin(), ::tolower);
                t.PutItem(word);
                totalwords++;
                word = "";
                c = '\0';
            }
        }

    }if(isalpha(word[0])){
        transform(word.begin(), word.end(), word.begin(), ::tolower);
        t.PutItem(word);
        totalwords++;
    }

    file.close();
    fout.open("results.txt");
    cout << "\nWord counts:\n\n";
    t.Print();
    t.Print2(fout);
    cout << "\nTotal number of words in text: " << totalwords << ".\n";
    fout << "\nTotal number of words in text: " << totalwords << ".\n";
    cout << "Number of distinct words appearing in text: "
        << distinctWord << ".\n";
    fout << "Number of distinct words appearing in text: "
        << distinctWord << ".\n";
    fout.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your input. What is your expected output. What output are you getting?

Comment: That's a lot of code. most of which are probably unrelated to your problem. Please try to create a [**Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that you can show us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to pass your output file stream to your 
`PrintTree(root);` too.

Right now you are printing to `cout` which will dump everything to whatever console your application is associated with.

The modified function after adding the `ofstream` parameter becomes:

```
void TreeType::PrintTree(Node* root, ofstream &fout) {
    if (root == nullptr)
       return;
    PrintTree(root->left, fout);
    fout << root->word << " " << root->count << endl;
    PrintTree(root->right, fout);
}
```

You will need to pass the `ofstream` object throughout in all callers of `PrintTree`